# join multiindex dataframe with single-index dataframe breaks multiindex format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas 1.1.3

I have one multi-index dataframe (not sure if this is the correct term) that looks as follows.

df1:

```
            A          B
       mean   max   mean max
name   

John    3      4     5    6
Cindy   1      6     7    8
Chris   3      5     5    5
```

df1.columns output MultiIndex([( 'A', 'mean'), ('A', 'max'), ( 'B', 'mean'), ('B', 'max')]).

1. Am I calling this in correct terminology? Is it supposed to be called Multi-level column?

I have df2 that looks like this:
df2:

```
 name      title
John     Data Engineer
Cindy    Data Analyst
Chris    Data Scientist
```

Left joining df1 to df2 works successfully however it breaks multi-index formatting.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", left_index=True, right_on="name")
```

outputs

```
       (A, mean)    (A, max)    (B, mean)     (B, max)     title
name   
John       3           4            5            6         Data Engineer
Cindy      1           6            7            8         Data Analyst
Chris      3           5            5            5         Data Scientist
```

I want to perform join while keeping multi-index format, desired dataframe should look like this:

```
                  A                       B                  title
          mean         max          mean       max
 name   
John       3           4            5            6         Data Engineer
Cindy      1           6            7            8         Data Analyst
Chris      3           5            5            5         Data Scientist
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I calling this in correct terminology? Is it supposed to be called
> Multi-level column?

Yes, it is MultiIndex. What you se is just the string representation of the index. On higher version of Pandas, `df.columns` would give you:

```
MultiIndex([('A', 'mean'),
            ('A',  'max'),
            ('B', 'mean'),
            ('B',  'max')],
           )
```

The problem here is how you view your expected output, specifically the last column? Is it still MultiIndex? If so, what's the second level value?

That said, you can match the expected output with:

```
df.join(df2.set_index('name').rename(columns=lambda x: (x,"")))
```

Output:

```
         A        B               title
      mean max mean max                
name                                   
John     3   4    5   6   Data Engineer
Cindy    1   6    7   8    Data Analyst
Chris    3   5    5   5  Data Scientist
```

Comment: Thanks! But `pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":[1,2,3], "c":[3,3,3]}).set_index(["a", "b"]).index` this also says it is MultiIndex, so they are both called that?

Comment: Yes, both multi-leveled columns and multi-leveled index are called `MultiIndex`.

Comment: Is there a reason multi-leveled columns are called multiIndex? why not just call them multi-leveled columns?

Comment: Idk, I'm not the developer. My wild guest is `MultiIndex` is easier to write than `MultiLeveledIndex`.

Comment: Although this is very nice, it should be noted, that it gives you a single-index column (where the column names are tuples) in case you switch the order, i.e. ``df2.set_index('name').rename(columns=lambda x: (x,"")).join(df)``. But in any case, there is now a warning that this will not work any more in the near future.
Right now, my solution therefore is: ``df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1); df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, '') if np.isscalar(i) else i for i in df.columns])``
Any improvement on this is very welcome.